# Firefox image loads partially then breaks

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, firefox

I'm seeing some unexpected behavior when trying to load images on firefox. In my web application, I've built a graph. When I hover points on the graph, a tooltip is rendered, and within that tooltip an image (along with some text). When I render this on firefox, the image begins to show loaded content, and then once fully loaded, is replaced with the broken page icon. (See imgur gif below).

The images are being loaded from Amazon S3, which could be relevant. Also, this tooltip is being rendered by Recharts library, in plain js, the component is being imported in my React app.
The line to load the image is simply:

`<img src={image_url} width="336px" />`

This occurs on my current install of FF (windows 10) as well as a MacOSX fresh firefox install (with no add-ons). This does not occur in any chrome installation (tested on 5+ computers) nor in microsoft edge.

I inspected the network calls to load the images and found only these differences (but you might be able to see something I am missing in the live link to the webapp below):

- In chrome, the Referrer Policy was `strict-origin-when-cross-origin`, while in FF it defaulted to `no-referrer-when-downgrade` (however I locally set the firefox referral policy value (via attribute on the `img`) to `strict-origin-when-cross-origin` and `origin-when-cross-origin`, no change occurred).
- Here is the chrome `Accept` header: `image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8`
  versus the firefox: `image/webp,*/*`
- Lastly, `Accept-Language` was different, with chrome `en-US,en;q=0.9` when Firefox has `en-US,en;q=0.5`.

Here's a webm + gif displaying the behavior I'm seeing:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nel0i.jpg
Here's the live website where this is occurring:
http://52.53.193.14:3000/viewcount/esl_csgo/2020-10-11_09-11-21

Comment: did you try resize your image to some smaller? You are using an incredible size for thumbail, you should use 2 images.

Comment: Also you are getting a lot of redirects and 404, cross site blocks and other things, check your network details in your browser

Comment: I've tried hosting the files via AWS cloudfront as well, and this doesn't change the behavior I see (still loads in chrome / other browsers, but not in firefox).

Comment: I still believe you have two problems, 1) the size 2) the cross site security problem (resolved with politics on the server side)

Answer (score 0):

As @Leandro [pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64381562/firefox-image-loads-partially-then-breaks/66127591#comment113844858_64381562), the problem was image size.

> did you try resize your image to some smaller? You are using an incredible size for thumbail, you should use 2 images. I still believe you have two problems, 1) the size 2) the cross site security problem (resolved with politics on the server side)

I didn't know that the larger images would break, that certainly surprised me. I expect it might have to do with too many large images overloading the allowed memory of the page. (However this occurred even on the first load).